# Getting null as a response body from retrofit api client

Tags: android, twitter, retrofit

I pass "-1" for the first parameter and my twitter id as a second parameter but always get null as a response body from retrofit
How can I solve this problem ?

ApiInterface.java :-

```
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface ApiInterface
{
    @GET("followers/list.json")
    Call<List<Follower>> getFollowers(@Query("cursor") String  cursor,@Query("user_id") String userid);
}
```

ApiClient.java

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit;
    public static Retrofit getApiClient()
    {
        if(retrofit==null)
        {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a logging request interceptor?  It might show you what's going wrong.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't solve the problem too